# nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/config/AopNamespaceUtils

Tags: java, spring

I have a switchyard application, there I have a bean class defined for loading application context.

However, whenever I am trying to load the application context I am getting below error:

```
**30 May 2015 15:52:15,510 ERROR [com.ip.fsw.tt.db.DBHandlerBean] (MSC service thread 1-8) DBHandlerBean|0|Error occured while bean initialization : Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/config/AopNamespaceUtils**
```

**Here is my applicationContext.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans default-init-method="beanInit" default-destroy-method="beanDestroy"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="decryptPropertyConfigurer" class="com.alu.ipprd.oss.common.util.DecryptPropertyConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:tt-db.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database" />
        <property name="user" value="tt" />
        <property name="password" value="tt" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="3000" />
        <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="namingStrategy" class="org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy"></bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="namingStrategy">
            <ref bean="namingStrategy" />
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.ip.fsw.tt.db.models.TTroubleticket</value>
                <value>com.ip.fsw.tt.db.models.TTroubleticketalarm
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${MY_SQL_DIALECT}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${SHOW_SQL}</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.FlushMode">${FLUSH_MODE}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${HBM_2_DDL_AUTO}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="genericDao" class="com.ip.fsw.tt.db.dao.GenericDao"
        abstract="true">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tTroubleticketDao" class="com.ip.fsw.tt.db.dao.TTroubleticketDao"
        parent="genericDao" />

    <bean id="tTroubleticketalarmDao" class="com.ip.fsw.tt.db.dao.TTroubleticketalarmDao"
        parent="genericDao" />

    <bean id="ttfacade" class="com.ip.fsw.tt.db.facade.DaoTicketFacade">
        <property name="tTroubleticketDao" ref="tTroubleticketDao" />
        <property name="tTroubleticketalarmDao" ref="tTroubleticketalarmDao" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Here is my DBHandler class, where I am trying to load the application context :**

```
package com.ip.fsw.tt.db;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.switchyard.component.bean.Service;

import com.ip.common.logging.jb.Logger;
import com.ip.fsw.tt.db.facade.DaoTicketFacade;

@Service(DBHandler.class)
public class DBHandlerBean implements DBHandler {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DBHandlerBean.class);
    public static DaoTicketFacade ttfacade;
    public DBHandlerBean() {
        logger.info("DBHandlerBean",0,"Loading AppContext","");
        if(loadAppContext()){
            logger.info("DBHandlerBean",0,"AppContext Successfully loaded","");
        }
    }

    private boolean loadAppContext() {
        try {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
            ttfacade = (DaoTicketFacade)context.getBean("ttfacade");
        } catch(BeansException e) {
            logger.error("DBHandlerBean",0,"Error occured while bean initialization : "+e.getMessage(),"");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("DBHandlerBean",0,"Error occured while loading the application context : "+e.getMessage(),"");
        } 
        if(ttfacade!=null){
            logger.info("DBHandlerBean",0,"Spring context loaded","");  
            return true;
        } else {
            logger.error("DBHandlerBean",0,"Spring context could not be loaded ","");
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public DaoTicketFacade getFacade() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please let me now how can I fix this issue.

**Edit:**

Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ip.tt</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform-tt</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>platform-tt</name>

    <properties>
        <switchyard.version>1.1.0.Final</switchyard.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.7.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.SP1</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.saxon</groupId> 
            <artifactId>saxonhe</artifactId> 
            <version>9.2.1.5</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-security</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-remoting</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alu.ipprd.aor.common.log</groupId>
            <artifactId>aor-plf-common-logging</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Switchyard Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-bean</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-camel</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-rules</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-camel-quartz</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-soap</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-api</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-transform</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-validate</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-test</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-test-mixin-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Module Dependencies -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.SP1</version>
            <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/hibernate-core-4.2.0.SP1-redhat-1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
            <!-- <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar</systemPath> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId> <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId> 
            <version>2.7.2</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                switchyard-component-test-mixin-http
            </artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
                <artifactId>switchyard-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
                <!-- <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions> -->
                <configuration>
                    <scannerClassNames>
                        <param>
                            org.switchyard.transform.config.model.TransformSwitchYardScanner
                        </param>
                    </scannerClassNames>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have the `spring-aop` module on your classpath. All the code you included is fairly irrelevant, it would be much more useful to see your pom.xml.

Comment: I tried adding spring-aop dependency in pom.xml, but it thows some other exception which is :

nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor

So I thought this is something related to spring-tx dependency. But spring-tx dependency is already present in the classpath.

Comment: Stop mixing different version from a framework, you are mixing spring jars from different versions as well as for hibernate you are mixing versions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` is generally thrown when you do have the class during compile time but it is not present during run time.

Please check your maven dependencies thoroughly for any jar conflicts. This might be a possible cause for the NoClassDefFoundError.

Also check your pom.xml and navigate to the dependency hierarchy tab to verify if you do not see the same jar with different versions twice.

If you do have jar conflicts you would have to remove one of them based on your requirement of using the specific version.

In my case, the spring-aop jar was present in compile time, but when I was deploying my project to JBoss EAP server, it was not able to locate the spring-aop jar. So I added the spring-aop jar in the JBoss EAP modules directory and after that my project picked the jar file.

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing namespace versions (3.1, 3.0, 2.0).

Follow this exemple that is using 3.2

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
```

Comment: Mixing namespace versions isn't an issue, and it is recommended to use the version less xsds instead.

Comment: he using spring 4 in pom.xml

Comment: @ahmed.ettoumi When you expand the maven dependencies jar in eclipse, you can see that the higher version of jars also support the lower version xsds.

Comment: @amit4497, merci pour le détail :)